# Series of averages of convergent positive series is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I found many similar questions, but I'm having trouble with this one.
Let $a_n>0$ be a positive sequence such that $\sum a_n$ converges If $y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^na_j$, then $\sum y_n$ converges. This doesn't seem hard, but all comparisons and tests I've applied are being inconclusive. Not sure how to use the positivity of $a_j$ also. If it were monotone, I think it would be easier, but I don't see how this helps.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote this down correctly? Because $y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k>\frac{a_1}{n}$ will sum to infinity.

Comment: @QC_QAOA You are right, the exercise must be wrong then